# Is it possible to have a Cognito Form with 3 columns?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can you define a form with three columns instead of two?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As of July 1, 2016, Cognito Forms allows you to resize fields.  This would support having a form with 3 columns as well as more flexible designs (2 columns for part of form, 3 for another, 4 for another, etc).

---

I work in support for Cognito Forms.  We support only forms with two columns.

However, we are actively working on creating table fields which will allow for more columns within that field.  You can view information about that new field on our [public Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/cCSk5DYR/4-table-field).